# Execute command in time increments of 1 second on same line in terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7

This script I have is very simple.  Until the script is manually stopped, it prints, in the terminal, the current time every 1 second.  The only problem I've had thus far is the carriage return '\r' command used to go back and use the same line as before does not work as intended.  Instead of the time being overwritten each time, I get an output like this:

```
Good morning!
It's 03:10:13 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:14 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:15 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:16 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:17 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:18 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:19 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:20 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
It's 03:10:21 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017
```

Am I not allowed to do this on terminal? Is there a problem with the 1 second pause I'm putting in between?

Here is my code:

```
import time
import sys

print("Good morning!")
while True:
    time_str = "It's %I:%M:%S %p on %A, %b %d, %Y\r"
    print time.strftime(time_str)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Some extra information: I'm using a bash shell on an Ubuntu system

Comment: you have to use `end="\r"` in `print()` - not in `time_str`, and not in `format()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rewrite output in terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3488704/how-to-rewrite-output-in-terminal)

Comment: @Tagc I've read through them already and it didnt solve my problem. At furas, I've tried that already and edited my code to show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `end="\r"` in `print()` to replace default `end="\n"`

```
import time
import sys

print("Good morning!")
while True:
    time_str = "It's %I:%M:%S %p on %A, %b %d, %Y"
    print(time.strftime(time_str), end="\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

I use Linux Mint (based on Ubuntu) and `\r` works for me in terminal (but maybe Ubuntu use different terminal).

---

You get error with `end="\r"` so this means that you use `Python 2`, not `Pyhton 3` - and then you need `comma` at the end in `print` to skip default `\n`

```
import time
import sys

print "Good morning!"
while True:
    time_str = "It's %I:%M:%S %p on %A, %b %d, %Y\r"
    print time.strftime(time_str),  # <-- comma to skip "\n"
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried that too.  I am now getting a SyntaxError: invalid syntax pointing at the '=' in 'end='\r'.  I've updated my code

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me testing on Windows 10 within PyCharm (output: `Good morning!` and nothing else) and IDLE 3.6.0 (output: `Good morning!
It's 10:42:35 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017It's 10:42:36 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017It's 10:42:37 PM on Wednesday, Jan 25, 2017...`)

Comment: @Tagc it all depends on console/terminal - not all of them respect `\r`

Comment: @JordanPagni are you sure you use `Python 3` ? You could get this error if you use `Python 2`

Comment: @furas Sorry forget the syntax error, but it is still not printing on the same line

Comment: Thanks @furas for your efforts! Fortunately this is now working! I noticed you added the ',' at the end of the print statement, which fixed the issue.  How does that work?

Comment: maybe change terminal :)

Answer (score 1):

You must place the carriage return at the beginning of the text and replace the carriage end with ""

```
import time
import sys

print("Good morning!")
while True:
    time_str = "\rIt's %I:%M:%S %p on %A, %b %d, %Y"
    print(time.strftime(time_str), end="")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I tried that and is still not printing on the same line

Comment: +1, this works in Pycharm under Windows 10 nicely (IDLE is still problematic and I doubt any solution can be made to work for it).

Comment: Also successfully tested within a mintty terminal and a command prompt under Windows 10.

Comment: It might just be a problem with Ubuntu then, because none of these solutions are working it seems